# Sonar Jira plugin with an internal jira server

Tags: jira, sonarqube

Sonar jira plugin can't connect to the internal jira server.

In our company, connections to external resources must be established through a proxy. Our jira server is hosted internally, for example running at `http://myjira`.

In my browser's proxy settings, I must add the myjira hostname to the list of ignored hosts.

Is it possible to tell Sonar to do the same thing as my browser ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Although, this should not be a problem assuming that you are running both sonar and jira on the same network.

I would update your sonar.properties file and set the proxy settings for sonar .

```
#---------------------------------------------------------
# UPDATE CENTER
#---------------------------------------------------------

# The Update Center requires an internet connection to request  
# http://update.sonarsource.org
# It is activated by default:
#sonar.updatecenter.activate=true

# HTTP proxy (default none)
http.proxyHost=host
http.proxyPort=port

# NT domain name if NTLM proxy is used
#http.auth.ntlm.domain=

# SOCKS proxy (default none)
#socksProxyHost=
#socksProxyPort=

# proxy authentication. The 2 following properties are used for
# HTTP and SOCKS proxies.
http.proxyUser=user
http.proxyPassword=password
```